# File is not downloading completely

Tags: c#, stream, download

This is my C# code to download a ZIP file from my server. When I download I don't receive the file, but it is partially downloaded.

```
public static void Download(String strURLFileandPath, String strFileSaveFileandPath)
{
    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURLFileandPath);
    HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
    Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();
    byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];
    int bytesToRead = (int)inBuf.Length;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while (bytesToRead > 0)
    {
        int n = str.Read(inBuf, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
        if (n == 0)
            break;
        bytesRead += n;
        bytesToRead -= n;
    }
    try
    {

        FileStream fstr = new FileStream(strFileSaveFileandPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead);
        str.Close();
        fstr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I thing the problem is happening here

```
byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];
```

When I increase the value of `byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];` to `byte[] inBuf = new byte[10000000];`

The file is downloading perfectly.

But my problem is if I download files larger than 50 MB (eg.: 200 MB) .

This method is not good.

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your keyboard seems to have the same problem. :)

Comment: Dont you get a reponse in the header of he file size that your downloading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could copy directly from stream to stream using the [Stream.CopyTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) method.

Or even simpler: Use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class and its `DownloadFile` method to download the file. This solution would replace your complete method:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(strURLFileandPath, strFileSaveFileandPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay
But why the form is going not responding?

Comment: That's because the download is executed in the same thread as the UI. And while the file is being downloaded, the UI is not able to process any messages. You should use the [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196) method and attach an event handler to the `DownloadFileCompleted` event so you know when the download is finished. Be aware that your download method call will then return immediately. Any code that needs the complete local file must be put in the event handler!

Comment: Thanks for that.
i managed the problem with the background worker

I wish to set a progress bar for this. is the webclient has any event for the download progress?
if not how can i set a progress bar?

Comment: For that you have to switch back to the solution with the `WebRequest`. You can't use `CopyTo` neither. The answer by nunespascal would fit in here better. `bytesToRead` is the buffer size. In each loop, up to `bytesToRead` bytes are read from the request and written to the file. After that you can increase your progress count by `bytesRead`. `inBuf` has to be defined as `byte[bytesToRead]`. Then put the whole code in your background worker. But keep in mind that updating the UI from another thread is pretty tricky (this has been discussed on stackoverflow a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Write the file as you read it. That way, you won't have to keep all the bytes in memory before you write or finish downloading.

```
FileStream fstr = new FileStream(strFileSaveFileandPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
int bytesRead;
do
{
    bytesRead = str.Read(inBuf, 0, bytesToRead);
    fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead);
}while (bytesToRead > 0);

str.Close();
fstr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As fero suggested its best to use `Stream.CopyTo()`

However if your determined to do it the copy stream to stream manually way ( or need to know how to use streams in the future ) you should never manually specify the buffer size. You generally want to use the maximum size of buffer with no overlap to avoid excessive memory consumption, in the case of the ResponseSream you can get the `ContentLength` for your streamreader

```
 HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURLFileandPath);
 HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
 Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();
 byte[] inBuf = new byte[str.ContentLength];
 int bytesToRead = (int)inBuf.Length;
```

Also remember and `Flush()` your output.

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov I have edited to reflect and clarify, this isn't the best soltuion, but only a answer to his problem. The best solution is a copyto method avoiding manually iterating through streams.